# How change CSS properties for element child

Tags: html, css

For the given example:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu_top">Menu1<div class="sub_menu">SubMenu1</div></div>
    <div class="menu_top">Menu2<div class="sub_menu">SubMenu2</div></div>
    <div class="menu_top">Menu3<div class="sub_menu">SubMenu3</div></div>
</div>
```

How can I change the display property for the respective childs elements?

I was trying the solution:

```
.menu_top .sub_menu{
    display: none;
}
.menu_top:hover div.sub_menu{
    display: block;
}
```

But all the "sub_menu" are shown when the mouse is over any "menu_top".

Comment: The first answer solve my problem, but it was deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to display the `.sub_menu` when hovering over `.menu_top`?

```
.menu .menu_top:hover .sub_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector should be `.menu_top:hover` if you only want to display the respective child `.sub_menu` on hover.

See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/spBJH/

Answer (score 1):

[5.6 Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

A child selector matches when an element is the child of some element. A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by ">".

The following rule sets the style of all P elements that are children of BODY:

```
body > P { line-height: 1.3 }
```

The following example combines descendant selectors and child selectors:

```
div ol>li p
```

It matches a P element that is a descendant of an LI; the LI element must be the child of an OL element; the OL element must be a descendant of a DIV. Notice that the optional white space around the ">" combinator has been left out.

Answer (score 0):

You've got them switched.

```
.menu:hover = { do something when I hover over .menu }
```

I think what you want is:

```
.sub_menu:hover { this }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a minor change i think.

You have `.menu:hover` instead of `.menu_top:hover`

try this instead:

```
.menu .sub_menu{
    display: none;
}
.menu_top:hover div.sub_menu{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.menu_top:hover div.sub_menu {
    display:block;
}
```